# Changing Raw Background Color

Tags: html, colors, background, raw

I would like to change the background color of the raw but it wont change

i have typed but still wont change `<tr class="bg-green text-white">`

```
<table border="0" class="table-striped" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
   <thead>
     <tr class="bg-green text-white">
        <th style="text-align:center">الترتيب</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">النادي</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">لعب</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">فاز</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">تعادل</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">خسر</th>
        <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell" style="text-align:center">له</th>
        <th class="d-none d-sm-table-cell" style="text-align:center">عليه</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">فارق</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">نقاط</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap you can use some common class to change the background color of the row. like-

```
<!-- On rows -->
<tr class="table-active">...</tr>

<tr class="table-primary">...</tr>
<tr class="table-secondary">...</tr>
<tr class="table-success">...</tr>
<tr class="table-danger">...</tr>
<tr class="table-warning">...</tr>
<tr class="table-info">...</tr>
<tr class="table-light">...</tr>
<tr class="table-dark">...</tr>

<!-- On cells (`td` or `th`) -->
<tr>
  <td class="table-active">...</td>
  
  <td class="table-primary">...</td>
  <td class="table-secondary">...</td>
  <td class="table-success">...</td>
  <td class="table-danger">...</td>
  <td class="table-warning">...</td>
  <td class="table-info">...</td>
  <td class="table-light">...</td>
  <td class="table-dark">...</td>
</tr>
```

[Bootstrap Ref](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/)

But if you are trying to change using only html and css, then you can try it like this.

```
tr{
  background-color: blue;
}
```